# How to define global constant when creating Web component?

Tags: javascript, class, scope, declaration, web-component

I am creating custom web component "upload-widget", and declaring three constants in constructor to be referenced in functions later:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <div id="dropper-zone">
    <input type="file" name="file_input" id="file_name">
    <button type="button" id="upload_btn">Upload</button>
    <div id="upload_status"></div>
  </div>
  `;

class UploadWidget extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

    const FILE_NAME = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("file_name");
    const UPLOAD_BUTTON = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("upload_btn");
    const UPLOAD_STATUS = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("upload_status");


  };

  upload_action() {
    if (!FILE_NAME.value) {
    console.log("File does not exists");
        return;
    UPLOAD_STATUS.innerHTML = 'File Uploaded';
  };

  connectedCallback() {
    UPLOAD_BUTTON.addEventListener("click", () => this.upload_action());
  }
}

customElements.define('upload-widget', UploadWidget);
```

This code fails since Javascript does not recognize the declared constants in the "connectedCallback()" nor in the function "upload_action()". Moving the declaration to either of the functions makes the constants valid only for the function scope, not beyond.
How do I declare constant/variable valid for the whole scope of the class including functions?

Comment: *Variables* declared with `let`/`const`/`var` are always only accessible inside the scope (in this case the `constructor` function) they were declared in. And no, you don't want them to become global constants, you want different values for each instance of `UploadWidget`. So make them object properties of your instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare them as class variables, so your `constructor` would look like:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

    this.FILE_NAME = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("file_name");
    this.UPLOAD_BUTTON = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("upload_btn");
    this.UPLOAD_STATUS = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("upload_status");
  };
```

Later in the code you can access them as `this.UPLOAD_BUTTON`.

Advice: Try to use camelCase when naming variables, it looks more "javascripty". So instead of `this.UPLOAD_BUTTON` write `this.uploadButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Note your template use is a bit bloated, you can do:

```js
 constructor() {
    let html = `
         <div id="dropper-zone">
           <input type="file" name="file_input" id="file_name">
           <button type="button" id="upload_btn">Upload</button>
           <div id="upload_status"></div>
         </div>`;
    super() // sets AND returns this scope
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
      .innerHTML = html;
  }
```